# Unity 2D: Add Animations to Instantiated child components/De-sync animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I'm working on a project where I need to animate a group of butterflies, which exist as instantiated children components. I was able to add an animation to the parent components and have the child components inherit from that, but the issue is that the animations are synced. We're talking about ~100 instantiated objects, so I'm looking for an automated solution.

```
// Portion of Flock Agent Class
void Start()
    {
        offset = Random.Range(0, 8);

        agentCollider = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
        agentFieldOfView = GetComponent<AgentFieldOfView>();
        //Animation
        anim = GetComponentInParent<Animator>();
        anim.SetFloat("Offset", offset);
        
        
    }
```

This is what I have so far in my Flock Agent class, which gives me the following results. The picture shows 'Flock Orange: Sprite missing,' and the animations still synced. Current state

[image]

Thank you,
Onion.

Comment: To the missing part: It means you either renamed or changed the hierarchy of the animated thing (the animations store the property path by names as string so basically any renaming / parenting etc will break animations) .. or it can mean you just do not have the object with the animator component (or an object in its hierarchy) selected

Comment: And to the syncing, if they all use the same `AnimatorController` asset then yes they get all synced .. you will need to make clones of the controller